# Integração Selenium com Testlink

Tags: java, testes, selenium-webdriver, junit

Estou tento um problema para fazer a integração do Selenium com o Testlink, pois ao utilizar no meu método de teste o try/catch com AssertionError, quando o teste dá falha o resultado do mesmo no testlink é apresentado correto (na cor vermelha), porém no junit ele é apresentado como sucesso(barra na cor verde).

Já se eu utilizo no  meu método de teste o try/catch com o Exception, no junit é apresentado o status correto do teste (barra vermelha para falha), mas já no testlink só é apresentado o status de sucesso (cor verde), mesmo com o teste falhando.

Como eu poderia resolver esse problema?

```
@Test
public void VerificaTituloGoogle() throws Exception {
    try {
        dr = new FirefoxDriver();
        dr.get("http://www.google.com");
        dr.manage().window().maximize();

        Assert.assertEquals("Googless", dr.getTitle())
    TestLinkIntegration.updateResults("VerificaTituloGoogle", null, TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_PASSED);
    //resultado = TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_PASSED;
}catch(AssertionError ea) {
    TestLinkIntegration.updateResults("VerificaTituloGoogle",ea.getMessage(), TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_FAILED);
      } 
}
```